# Computation left to the reader in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I'm studying QFT using Peskin & Schroeder and I have some problem with the two following computation which are left to the reader:

1.
 $$H = \int{d^3x \int{\frac{d^3pd^3p'}{(2\pi)^6} e^{i(p+p')x} \{-\frac{\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_{p'}}}{4}} (a_p-a_{-p}^{\dagger})(a_p'-a_{-p'}^{\dagger})+\frac{-p \cdot p'+m^2}{4\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_p'}}(a_p+a_{-p}^{\dagger})(a_{p'}+a_{p'}^{\dagger}))\}}$$ 
$$ = \int{\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\omega_p(a_p^{\dagger}a_p+\frac{1}{2}[a_p,a_p^\dagger])}. \tag{2.31}$$

For (2.31) I am stuck after the parentheses multiplication, I tried to use the commutator to remove some pieces but I don't know how to continue.

2.
$$<0|\phi(x)|p>=<0|\int{\frac{d^3p'}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2e_{p'}}}(a_{p'}e^{ip'\cdot x}+a_{p'}^{\dagger}e^{-ip'\cdot x})\sqrt{2E_p}a_p^{\dagger}|0>}.\tag{2.42}$$

For (2.42) after bringing $<0|$ inside the integral $a_{p'}^\dagger$ goes away because of $<0|$ then I'm left with $$<0|a_p'|p>=<p'|p>= 2E_p\delta(p-p')$$ which gives an unwanted factor of $2E_p$.

My result for 2.42 is $$\int{d^3p e^{ipx} 2E_p}$$ instead of $$e^{ipx}$$

Comment: Comment to the layout (v3): Note that P&S use boldface to denote 3-vectors.

Comment: 1. What exactly is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to make the two computation; for the first I tried to multiply the parentheses but I'm stuck after that; for the second I brought <0| inside the integral so as to remove a^{dagger} and after that i get a wrong result

Comment: I understood that a^{dagger} creates particle on the right and annihilates on the left while a does the opposite being one the adjoint of the other; why it's not like this?

Comment: Creation and annihilation operators create momentum-space particle modes with a normalization factor that you haven’t included. It is true that $\langle 0|a_{p’}\propto\langle p’|$, but what’s the proportionality constant?

Comment: On the right is $2E_p$, it's the same on the left?